Handlebars.Net, detecting whether a tag is used within an #each
I have a use case where I need to restrict a specific tag to be used within an #each only, and never outside. Is there a way I can do this back-end without creating a custom handler?
I have googled this, but I've not really come up with anything other than a custom handler, and our company would prefer we avoid using this if possible. I think for user familiarity reasons.
It might be more achievable on the front end, I don't know, but any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks
